# How to pass credentials through a fetch request in vuejs?

Tags: swagger-ui, fetch-api

I tried to pass credentials like this:

```
fetch(this.url + '/auth/login', {method:'GET', 
  headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('xxxx:xxxx')}})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json));
```

but it is giving this error in console:

```
GET https://stagingapi.pikflick.com/auth/login 404 (Not Found)
```

I tried another way:

```
fetch(this.url + "/auth/login", {
      method: 'GET',
      credentials: 'include',
      redirect: 'follow',
      agent: null,
      headers: {
          "Content-Type": "text/plain",
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('xxxx:xxxx'),
      }
  });
```

It shows this error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://stagingapi.pikflick.com/auth/login' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy

Can anyone show me how to pass credentials? I am using swagger for the first time. Can anyone help. I will be very grateful.

Comment: If you get a 404 error, then the URL is incorrect. Are you following some form of API documentation? How are you supposed to authenticate to this service?

Answer (score 0):

Propably you sould add / at the end of the fetched url like

```
fetch(this.url + '/auth/login/'...
```